# What does |= (pipe equal) sign do in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I saw a piece of code in a project where following is written:

```
 move = Move.create({
    'name': repair.name,
    'product_id': repair.product_id.id,
    'product_uom': repair.product_uom.id or repair.product_id.uom_id.id,
    'product_uom_qty': repair.product_qty,
    'partner_id': repair.address_id.id,
    'location_id': repair.location_id.id,
    'location_dest_id': repair.location_dest_id.id,
    'restrict_lot_id': repair.lot_id.id,
})
moves |= move
moves.action_done()
```

What does the `|=` meaning here?

Comment: It does whatever the type of `moves` decides it does. It generally means "bitwise or" or "set union" and assign and should generally be equivalent to `moves = moves | move`

Comment: Looks like the [set union operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).  Presumably the `Move` class overloads this to allow for operands of type `Move`

Comment: FYI: `set` is now a builtin in type: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: I wasn't sure how does the class interact with this operator. Thanks Rob.

Comment: @AChampion thanks for the information. I am trying to follow those operators. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @AChampion already mentioned in the first question comment, it could be "bitwise or" or "set union". While this question has Odoo as context, it is "set union" for the Odoo class `RecordSet`.

For your example: It's the same as `moves = moves | move` and means a union of `moves` and `move`.

This class was introduced with the new API on Odoo 8. For other operators look into the official doc of Odoo.

Answer (score 15):

It's a compound operator, when you say: `x |= y` it's equivalent to `x = x | y`

The `|` operator means `bitwise or` and it operates on integers at the bit-by-bit level, here is an example:

```
a = 3    #                (011)
         #                 |||
b = 4    #                (100)
         #                 |||
a |= b   #<-- a is now 7  (111)
```

Another example:

```
a = 2    #                (10)
         #                 ||
b = 2    #                (10)
         #                 ||
a |= b   #<-- a is now 2  (10)
```

So each bit in the result will be set if that same bit is set in either of the two sources and zero if both of the two sources has a zero in that bit.

The pipe is also used on sets to get the union:

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {2,3,4}
c = {4,5,6}
print(a | b | c)  # <--- {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score -1):

It simply means `moves = move | moves`.

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from your answer?